# Jar files for DL4J - using DL4J without building using Maven

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j

I want to use DL4J [https://deeplearning4j.org/] and tried the instructions on the setup guide [https://deeplearning4j.org/gettingstarted]. I am facing problems while building using Maven (build failure). Do I need to really use Maven to build everything. I just want to write some basic programs and run the examples which comes with DL4J. I am unable to find a list of jar files which i can import into my project and compile the examples. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I am facing problems while building using Maven (build failure)* Please share the exact problem with description and related stack trace from logs.

Answer (score 1):

The developers suggest to stick to Java 8 to avoid dependency-problems with Maven. If you are using Java 9 or OpenJDK (like on Linux), consider a switch to Java 8 to get Maven running.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to use IntelliJ IDE which manages automatically dependencies download and integration with maven.

If you're already using IntelliJ try to remove m2 folder (which contains all maven dependencies) and choose auto-import option in settings of the IDE.

You can try to use the last maven version too by download it and then configuring it into settings.

Like *gurvinder372* said, more information about your problem should be great for us.